# How to free shipping in Opencart based on total quantity?

Tags: opencart

My client requires Free shipping when Quantity Greater than or equal to 1000(qty>=1000).

Comment: Configure it via admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note : It's not recommended to make the direct changes in the core
>   files. You can make the vqmod for the same changes.

(1) Need to enable Free shipping from admin panel

Go to Admin -> Extensions-> shipping-> Free shipping -> Enable it

(2) Open file catalog/model/shipping/free.php and search for

```
if (!$this->config->get('free_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        }
```

and replace below code

```
 if (!$this->config->get('free_geo_zone_id') && ($this->cart->countProducts())>=1000) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows && ($this->cart->countProducts())>=1000) {
            $status = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using Free Shipping Plus that allow a lot of customizations on offering free shipping to our customers.